# How to add borders to a Responsive Table in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble with adding borders to a responsive table using bootstrap.

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="table-responsive text-center">

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead> ... </thead>
        <tbody> ... </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

The bordered table works only if I remove the "table-responsive" class.

What is my code missing so it works with this class as well class?

Comment: Seems to be working just fine https://jsfiddle.net/t1te9ccy/1/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith It's not. Remove "table-responsive" from the first example and you will see that the outer border will show.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like your panel class has one CSS property

`.panel>.table-bordered, .panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered {border:0;}`

and that makes your table's outer border invisible. You can explicitly provide

`border: 1px solid #ddd !important;` if necessary.

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="table-bordered table-responsive text-center">

    <table class="table table-bordered" style="border: 1px solid #ddd !important;">
        <thead> ... </thead>
        <tbody> ... </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can remove the panel class and use something else. That might also work. You can always look to inspect element to see what classes and what CSS property any element is using.

Still, you won't get the border. Also, make sure that the table's border color and background color are not the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it did not solve the issue, maybe I had to be more explicit, the table has borders between elements but it does not have outter border delimiting the table itself. I'm looking to add does borders

Comment: Check answer again. That was panel class's css that overrides table's border.

Comment: Extra colon in the CSS above. Fixed: `border: 1px solid #ddd !important;`

Answer (score 3):

I also see this issue by chance. It is very interesting that I found:

inside a media query `screen and (max-width: 767px)`, which means on a narrow-screen device,
or inside a panel,

`.table-responsive > .table-bordered` are set to have no borders in Bootstrap3. I don't know any reason for Bootstrap intentionally doing this.

That part of Bootstrap3 source code looks like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
...
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered {
    border: 0;
  }
...
}

.panel > .table-bordered,
.panel > .table-responsive > .table-bordered {
  border: 0;
}
```

Update: I kind of know the reason why Bootstrap is doing that. For narrow screen, `<div class="table-responsive">` has a border itself. Also, if a bordered table is a direct child of `<div class="panel">`, the panel would act like a border of that table. So Bootstrap intentionally removed the outer border of your table inside these divs.

You are not missing anything in your code. You are just not using it the way Bootstrap recommends.

Comment: What is he doing that is against recommendations?